# Scroll window to top of div on click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

New to jquery

I have an accordion uses this:

```
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

 $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;


  });

})(jQuery);
```

One of the accordion sections is super long and when you click the next it opens above the content.

I am hoping for help on a way to scroll to the top of the parent div#left-area when the a tags are clicked instead of only sliding content up. I sure one of you pros knows how. Thanks in advance.

page is structured like:

```
<dl class="accordion">
<dt>title</dt>
 <dd>
  content
 </dd>
<dt>title2</dt>
 <dd>
  content2
 </dd>
<dt>title3</dt>
 <dd>
  content3
 </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code as such:

```
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

 $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#left-area").offset().top}, 300);

    return false;


  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @JoeBarrett that's okay, you should be able to accept it as the correct answer though. If not, its no big deal. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to clarify, you want other sections to close, and the window to scroll down to the ID of the heading of the open section in the accordion?

If you can post a URL or JS Fiddle it would be helpful, but something like this, maybe?

```
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
  allPanels.slideUp();
  $(this).parent().next().slideDown();      

  $('html, body').animate({ //if you're wanting the whole window to scroll down
    scrollTop: $("div#left-area").offset().top
  }, 1000);

  return false;
});
```

If you post a JSFiddle I can tinker with, I'll test and revise this (if it doesn't work as is -- I'm kind of assuming it won't, since not looking at the structure of your HTML, I feel like I may easily have overlooked something.)

EDIT: I think there's a better solution for this not using the individual ID to animate the scroll down, but I'd need to see an example of how you're structuring it.

Comment: Thank you ben, you are a codeStar. I used the other method though. THanks a million.

Comment: No problem -- SteamDev's solution is basically the same anyway, we posted at the same time.  Like I say, there might be a way to apply this solution more broadly using `$(this)` with a class instead of the ID `#left-area` as the target, but I'd have to see your HTML structure.